# Surprising and basic data structures

Tags: data-structures

I'm interested in surprising data structures that extend the things people learned in their first algorithm/data structure course. Usually by offering an additional operation at a very low cost.

I learned that one can create a dynamic array with $O(1)$ access and $O(1)$ amortized append a long time ago. I thought there is no way to remove the amortized cost. I saw a data structure only a few months ago that do both operations in [$O(1)$ non-amortized time](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1999/09/CS-99-09.pdf).

What are some other examples?

Comment: This is not, on principles, a good question. Far too imprecise, open
and subjective. However I think it may be useful to know what other
people find surprising or fascinating. That is why I am upvoting it.

Comment: “Surprising” is entirely dependent on what YOU expect. Furthermore this is not really a question, it's a call for a list of items. This [does not work on a questions and answers site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: You might like [cuckoo hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing).  Cuckoo hashing gives guaranteed worst-case (rather than average) O(1) lookups for [open-addressed hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing).  It also enables _deletions_  with double hashing.  The tradeoff is that insertion is more complicated, moves elements in the table, and occasionally requires a complete rehash.  (Although insertion is still O(1) on average.)  The paper is [Pagh; Rodler: Cuckoo hashing. _J. Algorithms_ 51(2):122-144, 2004](http://www.itu.dk/people/pagh/papers/cuckoo-jour.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I would not know what you learned or did not learn, What is surprising depends a lot on who is to be surprised. So your question is pretty much undefined.

All I can do for you (but I am no expert) is to mention one technique that impressed me when I first saw it, the skip lists of William Pugh. And more generally the use of randomness and  probabilistic techniques, actually not just in algorithmics but also in "proving" or in quickly identifying things that can then be formally proved (at high computational cost) to have this or that property.

Comment: I've found treaps, and in particular the randomized binary tree variant described in  Martínez; Roura: "Randomized binary search trees", _JACM_ 45(2):288–323, 1997, doi:10.1145/274787.274812 to be easier to implement and have higher performance than skip lists.  They were also invented before skip lists, and a skip list is approximately equivalent to a treap "laid side-ways."

Comment: As I said, I am not an expert. It is the idea that impressed me at the time. I think Pugh's work was published in CACM in 1990, and must have appeared in a conference a year or two earlier. But I would not know most things on that topic.